# How to test blokchain lottery using Chainlink VRFv2 and Chainlink Keeper?

Tags: chainlink, hardhat, chainlink-keepers

Thanks to [Patrick](https://github.com/alphachainio/chainlink-lottery) and after reading the Chainlink's [blog](https://blog.chain.link/how-to-build-a-blockchain-lottery/) on how to build blockchain lottery, I am eager to build a similar "version". It will be using the latest Chainlink's version of **VRFv2** and **Keeper**.

However, the supported test networks for VRFv2 and Keeper are **Rinkeby** and **Kovan**, respectively.

So any hint on how to approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now the one of the only testnet's both Keepers and VRF v2 are available on is the BNB testnet. You can test your application there until VRF v2 and keepers are available on the same Ethereum testnet.

References:
[Keepers Supported Chains](https://docs.chain.link/docs/chainlink-keepers/introduction/#supported-blockchain-networks)
[VRF v2 Supported Chains](https://docs.chain.link/docs/vrf-contracts/)

Comment: Yes, both works on BNB testnet!